# Calculate how much ethanol to add to petrol to get a desired blend

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, arithmetic

Take the following problem:

> **Data:**
>
> - I have $20$ liters of petrol in a tank:
> - Assume that **e85** is defined as $85\%$ of ethanol and $15\%$ of petrol;
> - Assume that petrol does not contain ethanol.
>
> **Problem:**
>   How much **e85** we have to add to the $20$ liters of petrol to get a blend of $40\%$ ethanol and $60\%$ petrol?

So, the only values I have to start with is $20$ liters of petrol and a desired percentage, which in this case is $40\%$.

Comment: You could show your effort.

Answer (score 3):

$$20(0.00) + x(0.85) = (20+x)(0.40)$$

Solving for $x$ will tell you how many liters of e$85$ you need to add. To explain the equation in English, from left to right:

"I currently have $20$ liters of 0% ethanol. I need to add some amount $x$ of 85% ethanol. At the end of the day, I'll have $20+x$ liters of liquid total, and I'd like this liquid to be 40% ethanol."